# in-app-purchase BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR, Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Purchase action for in-app payment flow returns the error:

> BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR

with in_app_purchase package in Flutter.

I can list products and subscriptions in debug mode.
I created test user.
I upload the apk to closed testing channel with release build.
Test user can normally starts purchase flow.
In test purchase flow test credit card is selectable as always-accept option.

When I made a purchase (start a subscription), Android dialog closes "successfully" and purchase has count on the test user's subscription.

However when app turns back to Flutter; get the error code from purchaseUpdatedStream inside a PurchaseDetails object. So I can not start the "consume" process. By the way I can not purchase the item again, so It acting like consumed without any consume operation processed.

The error: BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR 5.

What could be cause this?

**Again**: User successfully starts the subscription. It can be seen in Play Store page for the Application.

**CODE UPDATE**

I tried with one time item not a subscription. The result remains same I think.

Test Environment:
Package: in_app_purchase: 0.3.0+3,
Debug build - Release build,
Real product which is created from Play Console,
Test user.

Purchase update listener:

```dart
InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.purchaseUpdatedStream;
    _subscription = purchaseUpdates.listen((purchases) {
      _handlePurchaseUpdates(purchases);
    });
```

Purchase handler:

```
Future<void> _handlePurchaseUpdates(
    List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
  purchaseDetailsList.forEach((PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
    switch (purchaseDetails.status) {
      case PurchaseStatus.purchased:
        bool valid = await _verifyPurchase(purchaseDetails);
        if (valid) {
          InAppPurchaseConnection.instance
              .consumePurchase(purchaseDetails)
              .then((BillingResultWrapper resultWrapper) async {
            /*

              I get the error here.
              purchaseDetails.status equals "PurchaseStatus.purchased" but
              After consumePurchase method "Item is not owned by user" 
              comes with resultWrapper object.
              
            */
            await deliverProduct(purchaseDetails);
          }).catchError((e) {});
        } else {}
        break;
      case PurchaseStatus.pending:
        print("Purchase pending...");
        break;
      case PurchaseStatus.error:
        break;
      default:
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: According to Google that error is returned when "Invalid arguments provided to the API." Can you share some code?

Comment: @enc_life I added some code.

Comment: I've posted a solution for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63985943/how-can-i-dd-in-app-purchase-functionality-to-my-flutter-app/65976171#65976171