# Flutter, in_app_purchase is seriously hard to test

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, flutter-dependencies

After looking at the somewhat poor in_app_purchase pub dev documentation, after distributing the test version several times, I succeeded in sending the internal test url to the test device to download it.

However, as soon as I entered the in_app_purchase screen with a real device, an app termination dialog error appeared and the app was forcibly turned off.

I am really badly angry now.

I don't understand why it made it so difficult to test, but I can't even see what caused the error.

I did exactly the same as the documentation example. And all of the dependencies are the same: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/in_app_purchase/example/lib

I can't continue the closed test review process until no errors are seen, and I'm crazy.

I really need help. How can I implement this in_app_purchase while viewing error log cat normally?

Comment: Did u get any help in the meantime. I have the same problem. There is very little information to go on. Could u share what u found out?

Comment: @Ride Sun yah it was so annoying I agree there is too little information. it was maybe AndroidManifest something bill dependency. and I recommend you to launch on cmd not on Android Studio too it is more easy to see logs. and you have to release alpha beta also

Comment: had you implemented properly. Can you please share your in app purchase code with me. I'm going mad to handle it

Comment: You should open a ticket in their github for this. I agree. The documentation is pretty hard.